# Old tags on my Tumblr have stopped working. Can I fix them?

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-tags

I have a comic book Tumblr where I track every comic book I read (sidenote: I know this is useless, it's Tumblr). I keep track of the comics with tags (series title, publication year, writer, artist and publisher). I've noticed that some of the oldest tags on my Tumblr have stopped working even though they still appear on the post. For example, when I click on "X-Force"...

[image]

...it tells me the URL I requested could not be found.

[image]

I guess there's a limit to the amount of tags Tumblr can remember? Is there anyway to free up tag space (like deleting typo tags)? Is there any way to get these tags to work again?

---

UPDATE: In trying to find a pattern between which tags do and don't work. Here are the first tags I ever used (back on 1-1-10):

- Uncanny X-Men (used approx. 55 times; **does NOT work**)
- 2010 (used 477 times, **still works**)
- Matt Fraction (used 72 times, **still works**)
- Terry Dodson (used 14 times, **still works**)

So it doesn't seem to have to do with how many entries are in the tag. **I think it might have to do with the hyphen in the titles of some comics** (Uncanny X-Men and X-Force do not work). Is that it? These used to work, I swear (I would not have continued to use tags with hyphens if they did not work).

Comment: By oldest, do you mean when they were created or when they were last used?

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller I updated my post. I think it might have to do with the hyphen in the tags. Tumblr used to allow hyphens in tags, perhaps not anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that tags with hyphens have been dashed.

Looks like Tumblr pulled support for tags with hyphens (`-`) as [far back as December 2011](http://touchreceptors.tumblr.com/post/13961717827/recently-i-noticed-that-any-tag-using-the-word). If you email them you'll get something along the following:

> Tumblr is no longer supporting tags with hyphens. This change has been made to ensure consistency in tags and tag searches.
>
> We are aware that this change is breaking tag filter links in some cases. You may have to remove hyphens from your tags in order for your tag filter links to work.
>
> We apologize for any inconvenience this may cause.

From the [testing others have done](http://cutlerish.tumblr.com/post/4988854076/tumblr-oversight-tagged-posts-with-hyphens) it looks like they've made the switch in order to allow searching to favour tags with a space in them.